# How to get the tables from AOT query in ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++

I have drop down in one page, I am selecting AOT query in first page then i will click on next button, then it has to show tables related to that query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a query name, you can loop through all of its datasources like this:

```
str queryName = "ActivityListOpen";
int i, dbcount;
QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
Query query = new Query(queryName);
dbcount = query.dataSourceCount();

for (i = 1;  i <= dbcount; i++)
{
    qbds = query.dataSourceNo(i);
    info(qbds.name());
}
```

You can also use `table()` method on `QueryBuildDataSource` to retrieve table Id.

Comment: Can you please tell me , how we can use table () method on QueryBuildDataSource

Comment: `qdds.table()` returns int representing table id. You can then use `tableId2Name` function to get table name: `info(strFmt("%1", tableId2name(qbds.table())));`

Comment: Ya Okay, Understood. Thank you Maxim Lazarev